# How do I open a LMDB database in Java?

Tags: java, lmdb

I am trying to open a LMDB database using its Java API.

This is my `Database` class:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.lmdbjava.Dbi;
import static org.lmdbjava.DbiFlags.MDB_CREATE;
import org.lmdbjava.Env;
import org.lmdbjava.Txn;

public class Database {

    private String dbName;
    private String dbDirectoryName;
    private File dbDirectory;
    private Env<ByteBuffer> dbEnvironment;
    private Dbi<ByteBuffer> db;

    public Database(String _dbDirectoryName, String _dbName) {

        dbName = _dbName;
        dbDirectoryName = _dbDirectoryName;
        dbDirectory = new File(dbDirectoryName);

        dbEnvironment = Env.create().setMapSize(1_073_741_824).setMaxDbs(1).open(dbDirectory);
        db = dbEnvironment.openDbi(dbName, MDB_CREATE);

    }        

    public void Close() {
        dbEnvironment.close();
    }


}
```

And my main class:

```java
public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Database db = new Database("./data", "DB.TEST");

    }

}
```

I have double check that directory `data` exists.

I get the following error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnr/ffi/byref/PointerByReference
    at org.lmdbjava.Env$Builder.open(Env.java:460)
    at org.lmdbjava.Env$Builder.open(Env.java:486)
    at database.Database.<init>(Database.java:41)
    at TestApp.main(TestApp.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jnr.ffi.byref.PointerByReference
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 4 more
```

This test tries to follow the existing documentation for LMDB Java API:

https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava/blob/master/src/test/java/org/lmdbjava/TutorialTest.java

Comment: You seem to be missing some dependencies

Comment: Do you run/build this through Maven? The project you link to references a couple of dependencies in its pom.xml that you will need to have on your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required type is in `jnr-ffi-[version].jar`.

Comment: Added jnr-ffi-[version].jar with some dependencies and it works fine now. As project uses Maven and I was not using it, I missed dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Most Likely you are missing dependency, or jar file containing `jnr.ffi.byref.PointerByReference` class is missing from Classpath.

Check: 
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html

Depends on whichever tool you are using, add dependency to `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` or add it to classpath.